# Sample notation: When to use capital $N$ vs lowercase $n$?

Tags: terminology, sample, notation, psychology

In statistics and psychological research, what is denoted by capital $N$ vs lowercase $n$?

I work in psychological research and I've seen them used in two ways:

- Capital $N$ represents the entirety of our sample and lowercase $n$ are the groups in that sample. e.g. We run an RCT with $100$ participants, $50$ in control and $50$ in treatment, so $N = 100$ and $n = 50$ in each group.
- Capital $N$ represents the population that we recruit our study sample from and lowercase n is our study sample, e.g. We invite a random sample of $100$ registered voters out of the $162$ million citizens on the electoral roll, so $N = 162,000,000$ and $n = 100$ (assuming everyone we invite agrees to participate)

What is the conventionally accepted use of $N$ and $n$? Does it vary by field? What resources can I point to that clarify what each means?

Comment: There may be a distinction between theoretical analysis (upper case common for random variables and lower case for non-random variables or constants or indices) and practical research (upper case common for population and lower case for samples). Individuals may have other preferences and may choose what they think is clearer in individual pieces of work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say the second notation is common, although evidently not universal, namely that $n$ is used for sample size and $N$ for population size.

By accident, perhaps, rather than design, it matches a common distinction whereby roman letters are used for sample statistics and Greek letters for population parameters: $N$
is upper case in Greek as well as in many other languages. (Lower case $n$ in Greek is $\nu$, often used to denote the number of degrees of freedom.)

For subsamples, I agree with @Ben and widespread practice that subscripting $n$ to indicate particular subsample sizes seems natural as well as convenient, say $n_1, n_2;\quad n_\text M, n_\text F;\quad n_{\text{Control}}, n_{\text{Treat}}$.

It is often true, naturally, that we know sample size $n$
but we don't know the population size $N$. We can toss a coin for a sample $n=100$
times, but the size of the population of possible tosses $N$
is, if not infinite, then at least arbitrarily large.

Freedom of choice in notation is a virtue when you use it to express strong personal preferences and a vice when other people use it in ways you regard as non-standard or otherwise undesirable.

Answer (score 9):

I have worked with social, behavioral, and medical sciences and also read some statistics books and articles that aren't linked to one specific field. I don't think there is any real consistency here, at least not in actual usage, even if you can point to references that say "this is right!"

Usually it is clear from context. Other times it is explicitly stated. Unfortunately, sometimes neither one is done and the poor reader is confused.

Answer (score 9):

Although the notation is not universal, I typically see (and use) $N$ used to denote population size and $n$ used to denote sample size.  For subgroups in the sample I find it simpler to use subscripts --- e.g., $n_M$ and $n_F$ for the size of the subsamples of males and females respectively.

Answer (score 4):

In psychological research, the convention goes in the first way you describe. APA (2020) in Section 6.44 Statistical Symbols and Abbreviations of "American Psychological Association Publication Manual (7th ed)" prescribes that

> *n* number of cases (generally in a subsample)
>
> *N* total number of cases
>
> *df* degrees of freedom
>
> ν (nu) degrees of freedom
>
> **Symbols for Population Versus Sample Statistics.** Population parameters
> are usually represented by [not italicized] Greek letters. Most
> estimators are represented by italicized Latin letters.
>
> **Symbols for Number of Subjects.** Use an uppercase, italicized *N* to
> designate the number of members in the total sample (e.g., *N* = 135).
> Use a lowercase, italicized *n* to designate the number of members in
> a limited portion or subsample of the total sample (e.g., *n* = 80 in
> the treatment group).
>
> **Standard, Bold, and Italic Type.** Statistical symbols and mathematical information in papers are prepared with three different
> type styles: standard (roman), bold, and italic. The same type style
> is used in text, tables, and figures. Use standard type for Greek
> letters, subscripts and superscripts that function as identifiers
> (i.e., are not variables, as in the subscript “girls” in the example
> that follows), and abbreviations that are not variables (e.g., log,
> GLM, WLS). Use bold type for symbols for vectors and matrices. Use
> italic type for all other statistical symbols.

In Section 6.22 Use of Italics, it requires to use italics for Latin letters used as statistical symbols or algebraic variables but do not italicize Greek letters. Therefore, the capitalized Greek letter $\text N$ (Nu) would not be italicized and may be visually indistinguishable from capital Latin letter N.

Comment: Such efforts are always double-edged. The APA are clearly trying to improve consistency and quality generally, which are admirable goals in the abstract.  In terms of the question in this thread:  the instruction to use $N$ for total sample size would leave me --and perhaps others -- floundering when I want a symbol for population size. I suspect that is less troublesome for psychologists than for some other groups. As I don't submit to APA journals, that one won't bite in my own work.

Comment: I guess it is because psychologists never have a fixed, known, or measurable population size. Otherwise they would use unitalicized ν and unitalicized N as Greek letters for population sizes.